# Logo not appearing on splash screen of progressive web

Tags: icons, manifest, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps

In these demos, there are logos on the splash screens.

https://addyosmani.com/blog/getting-started-with-progressive-web-apps/

I don't know what I am doing wrong in my manifest - I have an icon but it is not showing up on my splash screen.

My manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "short_name": "Weather Service",
  "name": "Weather Service",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "logo.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait",
 "background_color": "#FAFAFA",
  "theme_color": "#512DA8"
}
```

Do I need more than 1 image for it to appear on the splash screen?

Comment: It might have something to do with the exact path/directory where you placed your image file. Is the path correct?

Comment: The logo.png is read correctly as an icon (web app icon - when added to home screen) but it does not appear on the splash screen. The path is correct.

Comment: You can have just one logo on your manifest, example:

https://incredibleweb.github.io/samples/web-application-manifest/manifest.json

After adding to HomeScreen it works well. I suggest checking the image path, the size and the MIME type. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PWA is recommend to alway put icon at 192px as a minimum

> If you want to ensure that an icon will always be displayed consider that 48dp is the minimum image size we will display, which if you take the maximum density display currently supported (4x) then 48 * 4 = 192px. This is lucky because we need to 192px image for Add to Homescreen to work! Yay. Therefore, I would recommend always having 192px as the minimum sized icon and create 3 other versions at 256px, 384px and 512px. However, if you want to ensure that the user is not downloading too much data for the splash screen, especially on a low density device then you can go lower and Chrome will try to fetch the most appropriate image.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen

Comment: 192x192 makes the logo appear on all phones. Lower resolution logos appear on only phones with stock Android for some reason. Will put the 192x192 logo. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You can also validate your icons by using the "Add to homescreen" action under Chrome's dev tools (Application -> Manifest). This identified a `192x191px` image which was causing it to fail for me.

[image]